# What is the cheapest(less than 40 Euros) way to travel from Paris CDG to Brussels Midi?

Tags: trains, buses, paris, brussels

I will be landing in Paris CDG on April 7th 19:50 and would like to go to Brussels Midi(Hotel is booked) the same night. TGV and Thalys are too expensive(around  80 euros). Considering I will collect my baggage at 22:00 if there are no delays, is there a cheapest way to Brussels immediately or shall I layover in Paris for the night of 7th April start to Brussels next morning 8th april.

Note:I will have to be in Brussels atmoium on 8th by 11:00am.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately "cheapest" is a subjective term. To make this question answerable you'll have to specify what you mean by cheap. Hitchhiking might be the cheapest option but are you willing to do it?

Comment: Thank you. I would like the cost to be less that 40 euros.

Comment: @SaranrajAnnamalai you could check blablacar ;) it's a ride sharing website well known and used by a lot of people here. it'd cost you 20 to 25€ ;)